# R: Writing Functions for Nested Datasets

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
status  <- as.factor(status )

height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)

disease = sample(c(1, 0), 5000, replace = TRUE)

my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, gender, status, height, weight,disease)
```

Below is a code in which I take all male citizens - then take the 25% tallest male citizens, of these 25% tallest male citizens I take the 25% heaviest male citizens, and calculate how many of them have the disease:

```
part_1 = my_data[my_data$gender == "Male" & my_data$status == "Immigrant",]
part_1 = part_1 %>% arrange(desc(height))

limits = as.integer(seq(1, nrow(part_1), by = 0.25*nrow(part_1)))
limits = c(limits, nrow(part_1))

create_h <- function(part_1) {
    limits <- as.integer(seq(1, nrow(part_1), by = 0.25 * nrow(part_1)))
    limits <- c(limits, nrow(part_1))
    h_list <- list()
    for (i in 1:(length(limits) - 1)) {
        h_list[[i]] <- part_1[limits[i]:(limits[i + 1] - 1), ]
    }
    return(h_list)
}

h_list <- create_h(part_1)

for (i in seq_along(h_list)) {
    assign(paste0("h_", i), h_list[[i]])
}

###########################
part_2 = h_1 %>% arrange(desc(weight))


limits = as.integer(seq(1, nrow(part_2), by = 0.25*nrow(part_2)))
limits = c(limits, nrow(part_2))

create_w <- function(part_2) {
    limits <- as.integer(seq(1, nrow(part_2), by = 0.25 * nrow(part_2)))
    limits <- c(limits, nrow(part_2))
    w_list <- list()
    for (i in 1:(length(limits) - 1)) {
        w_list[[i]] <- part_1[limits[i]:(limits[i + 1] - 1), ]
    }
    return(w_list)
}

w_list <- create_h(part_2)

for (i in seq_along(w_list)) {
    assign(paste0("w_", i), w_list[[i]])
}

##############################


r1 = data.frame(gender = "male", status = "immigrant", min_height = min(w_1$height), max_height = max(w_2$height), min_weight = min(w_1$weight), max_weight = max(w_1$weight), disease_rate = mean(w_1$disease), total_count = nrow(w_1), disease_count = sum(w_1$disease == "1") )
```

The result looks something like this:

```
  gender    status min_height max_height min_weight max_weight disease_rate total_count disease_count
1   male immigrant   157.7242   173.7773   94.77408   117.1924          0.6          40            24
```

**My Question:** I am trying to extend this code to calculate the disease rate for all such combinations. Below, I tried to represent this as a tree diagram (in which my code corresponds to the "red box"):

[image]

(note: this is obviously just a small part of the tree - it is almost impossible to fully draw the whole tree)

**Can someone please show me how I take my general code structure and create results r_1, r_2.... r_n for all possible combinations in this tree - and then append them into a single dataset? Is there a quick way to do this with function/loop based approach?**

Thanks!

**Sources:** https://www.smartdraw.com/software/tree-diagram-maker.htm

Comment: You can do this with group_by. Give me a few minutes and I'll post an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by first binning the heights and weights and then using `table` and `aggregate`.

```r
# use 'cut' to bin height and weight, set the 
# values to the quantiles' intervals
qnt <- quantile(my_data$height)
lbls <- paste(names(qnt)[-5], names(qnt)[-1], sep = "-")
my_data$height_quant <- cut(my_data$height, qnt, labels = lbls, include.lowest = TRUE)
my_data$height_quant <- paste(my_data$height_quant, "Tallest")

# only compute the quantile's cut points, the labels 
# are built on the same lbls variable defined above
qnt <- quantile(my_data$weight)
my_data$weight_quant <- cut(my_data$weight, qnt, labels = lbls, include.lowest = TRUE)
my_data$weight_quant <- paste(my_data$weight_quant, "Heaviest")

cols <- c("gender", "status", "height_quant", "weight_quant", "disease")

tbl <- table(my_data[cols])
# compute proprotions table, don't show
# proportions(tbl)

ftbl <- ftable(tbl)
# compute proprotions table, don't show
# proportions(ftbl)

# coerce the tables to data.frames
df_tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
df_tbl_prop <- as.data.frame(proportions(tbl))
df_ftbl <- as.data.frame(ftbl)
df_ftbl_prop <- as.data.frame(proportions(ftbl))

# examples of results data.frames
# total counts
head(df_tbl)
#>   gender    status    height_quant    weight_quant disease Freq
#> 1 Female   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0   69
#> 2   Male   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0   61
#> 3 Female Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0   22
#> 4   Male Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0   26
#> 5 Female   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0   60
#> 6   Male   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0   44

# proportions of disease on total counts
head(df_ftbl_prop)
#>   gender    status    height_quant    weight_quant disease   Freq
#> 1 Female   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0 0.0138
#> 2   Male   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0 0.0122
#> 3 Female Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0 0.0044
#> 4   Male Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0 0.0052
#> 5 Female   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0 0.0120
#> 6   Male   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest       0 0.0088

# now compute proportions of disease per gender,
# status and height and weight quantiles
agg <- aggregate(Freq ~ gender + status + height_quant + weight_quant, df_tbl, \(x) x/sum(x))
colnames(agg[[ncol(agg)]]) <- paste0("disease.", 0:1)
agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])

head(agg)
#>   gender    status    height_quant    weight_quant disease.0 disease.1
#> 1 Female   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest 0.5036496 0.4963504
#> 2   Male   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest 0.5495495 0.4504505
#> 3 Female Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest 0.4782609 0.5217391
#> 4   Male Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest 0.6842105 0.3157895
#> 5 Female   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest 0.5172414 0.4827586
#> 6   Male   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 0%-25% Heaviest 0.4313725 0.5686275
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To include min and max of height and weight turned out to be more complicated than expected. Here is a full example, duplicating most of the code above. But getting the job done.

```r
# use 'cut' to bin height and weight, set the 
# values to the quantiles' intervals
qnt <- quantile(my_data$height)
lbls <- paste(names(qnt)[-5], names(qnt)[-1], sep = "-")
my_data$height_quant <- cut(my_data$height, qnt, labels = lbls, include.lowest = TRUE)
my_data$height_quant <- paste(my_data$height_quant, "Tallest")
tmp <- aggregate(height ~ height_quant, my_data, min)
my_data <- merge(my_data, tmp, by = "height_quant", suffixes = c("", "_min"))
tmp <- aggregate(height ~ height_quant, my_data, max)
my_data <- merge(my_data, tmp, by = "height_quant", suffixes = c("", "_max"))

# only compute the quantile's cut points, the labels 
# are built on the same lbls variable defined above
qnt <- quantile(my_data$weight)
my_data$weight_quant <- cut(my_data$weight, qnt, labels = lbls, include.lowest = TRUE)
my_data$weight_quant <- paste(my_data$weight_quant, "Heaviest")
tmp <- aggregate(weight ~ weight_quant, my_data, min)
my_data <- merge(my_data, tmp, by = "weight_quant", suffixes = c("", "_min"))
tmp <- aggregate(weight ~ weight_quant, my_data, max)
my_data <- merge(my_data, tmp, by = "weight_quant", suffixes = c("", "_max"))
rm(tmp)

cols <- c("gender", "status", 
          "height_quant", "height_min", "height_max",
          "weight_quant", "weight_min", "weight_max",
          "disease")

tbl <- table(my_data[cols])
# compute proprotions table, don't show
# proportions(tbl)

ftbl <- ftable(tbl)
# compute proprotions table, don't show
# proportions(ftbl)

# coerce the tables to data.frames
df_tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
df_tbl_prop <- as.data.frame(proportions(tbl))
df_ftbl <- as.data.frame(ftbl)
df_ftbl_prop <- as.data.frame(proportions(ftbl))

# examples of results data.frames
# total counts
head(df_tbl)
#>   gender    status    height_quant     height_min       height_max    weight_quant       weight_min       weight_max disease Freq
#> 1 Female   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0   69
#> 2   Male   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0   61
#> 3 Female Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0   22
#> 4   Male Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0   26
#> 5 Female   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0    0
#> 6   Male   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0    0

# proportions of disease on total counts
head(df_ftbl_prop)
#>   gender    status    height_quant     height_min       height_max    weight_quant       weight_min       weight_max disease   Freq
#> 1 Female   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0 0.0138
#> 2   Male   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0 0.0122
#> 3 Female Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0 0.0044
#> 4   Male Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0 0.0052
#> 5 Female   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0 0.0000
#> 6   Male   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest 111.5467983054 143.165045267515 0%-25% Heaviest 56.5309750696496 83.4974265243399       0 0.0000

# now compute proportions of disease per gender,
# status and height and weight quantiles
df_tbl <- df_tbl[df_tbl$Freq != 0, ]
agg <- aggregate(Freq ~ gender + status + 
                   height_quant + height_min + height_max + 
                   height_quant + weight_min + weight_max, 
                 df_tbl, \(x) x/sum(x))
colnames(agg[[ncol(agg)]]) <- paste0("disease.", 0:1)
agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])
agg[4:7] <- lapply(agg[4:7], \(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

head(agg)
#>   gender    status    height_quant height_min height_max weight_min weight_max disease.0 disease.1
#> 1 Female   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest   111.5468   143.1650   56.53098   83.49743 0.5036496 0.4963504
#> 2   Male   Citizen  0%-25% Tallest   111.5468   143.1650   56.53098   83.49743 0.5495495 0.4504505
#> 3 Female Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest   111.5468   143.1650   56.53098   83.49743 0.4782609 0.5217391
#> 4   Male Immigrant  0%-25% Tallest   111.5468   143.1650   56.53098   83.49743 0.6842105 0.3157895
#> 5 Female   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest   143.1659   149.8666   56.53098   83.49743 0.5172414 0.4827586
#> 6   Male   Citizen 25%-50% Tallest   143.1659   149.8666   56.53098   83.49743 0.4313725 0.5686275
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to display the min/max ranges for the height_quant and the weight_quant? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Thank you so much for your updates! I have been working on this question for a while now and I get so confused each time I try to approach i .... for example, I was always confused as to why the ranges sometimes overlap with each other (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552054/r-how-to-prevent-overlapping-ranges-within-nested-summary-groups) ....do you think this problem has now been resolved?

Comment: @stats_noob I think that [I_O's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552054/r-how-to-prevent-overlapping-ranges-within-nested-summary-groups#comment134972750_76552054)  to that question is very relevant and points to a solution to that problem. In this answer I first compute quantiles of the entire data set so there is no overlap. I think this is a more natural way of solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This was the point that was confusing me. In  this question, you can see that I am NOT calculating the quantiles on the entire dataset. Every time I make a split, I calculate the quantiles on the split data set. This was is what is confusing me: Suppose I use this approach : Why should there be "overlaps"?

Comment: By "overlap",, I am referring to a situation where a given patient (i.e. row of data) can be assigned to potentially two different groups (e.g. if a new male immigrant 155-165 cm and 65-71 kg appears - what is his disease rate? I should be able to identify the row corresponding to such a patient in the final table and identify his disease rate

Comment: I don understand: if I calculate quantiles after making splits (as I did in my question) - could this potentially result in a situation where a patient might appear in more than one row?

Comment: PS: If you make splits on each subset - I guess the splitting order could result in a different results table? If I choose to make the splits on weight before heights (even though both are still done in splits of 25%) - this could still result in a different disease rate being attributed to the same patient compared to if splits were made on height and then weight?

Comment: @stats_noob Yes it would. Thhe proportions depend on the order of split levels. Simple example: if you only have gender and height, and split by gender, then by bins of height  you will have 4 proportions but split the other way around to have only two, one per gender. The same goes if you complicate the example by adding weight to it.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! What do you think of the other points I raised? I.e  is overlap inevitable if done using my approach?

Comment: @stats_noob Once again, let me try to explain with the above simple example. If you split by gender and only then bin the data you will have heights within gender so for each gender the proportions add up to 1. If you bin the data first, the proportions within each gender add up to that gender's proportion, not to 1. If you want to avoid overlap, compute quantiles before splitting the data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```r
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

Patient_ID <- 1:5000
gender <- c("Male", "Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.45, 0.55))
gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant", "Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
status <- as.factor(status)

height <- rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
weight <- rnorm(5000, 90, 10)

disease <- sample(c(1, 0), 5000, replace = TRUE)

my_data <- data.frame(Patient_ID, gender, status, height, weight, disease)

my_data %>%
  group_by(gender, status, ntile(height, 4), ntile(weight, 4)) %>%
  summarise(
    min_height = min(height),
    max_height = max(height),
    min_weight = min(weight),
    max_weight = max(weight),
    disease_rate = mean(disease),
    disease_count = sum(disease),
    total_count = n(),
    .groups = "keep"
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    height_group = factor(`ntile(height, 4)`,
      levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("0-25%", "25-50%", "50-75%", "75-100%")
    ),
    weight_group = factor(`ntile(weight, 4)`,
      levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("0-25%", "25-50%", "50-75%", "75-100%")
    )
  ) %>%
  select(-starts_with("ntile"))
#> # A tibble: 64 × 11
#>    gender status  min_height max_height min_weight max_weight disease_rate
#>    <fct>  <fct>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
#>  1 Female Citizen       123.       143.       59.9       83.5        0.496
#>  2 Female Citizen       127.       143.       83.5       90.0        0.5  
#>  3 Female Citizen       116.       143.       90.3       97.0        0.496
#>  4 Female Citizen       119.       143.       97.1      121.         0.558
#>  5 Female Citizen       143.       150.       59.0       83.5        0.483
#>  6 Female Citizen       143.       150.       83.5       90.0        0.508
#>  7 Female Citizen       143.       150.       90.1       96.9        0.510
#>  8 Female Citizen       143.       150.       97.1      119.         0.407
#>  9 Female Citizen       150.       157.       60.1       83.5        0.5  
#> 10 Female Citizen       150.       157.       83.5       90.0        0.488
#> # ℹ 54 more rows
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: disease_count <dbl>, total_count <int>,
#> #   height_group <fct>, weight_group <fct>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You might consider `santoku::chop_quantiles()` to simplify the group creation.